# taken the liberty of

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following sentence is somehow ambiguous for me:

"Ambassador had already obtained from the Secretery an endorsement of the invitation he had taken the liberty of making to the King a few days earlier."

I have guessed something about the meaning of this sentence, but I am not sure.

Thanks very much, thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote out what you think the meaning is. Then, it will be more clear where the ambiguity is coming from. Also is there a **The** missing before ambassador?

Comment: The ambiguity is not with 'taken the liberty of', but whether 'he' refers to the Ambassador or the Secretary (presumably it means the Ambassador).

Comment: Hi! I geussed the meaning so: "The Ambassador was allowed by the secretary to invite the king to go to their country." (Note; The king was encounter a revolution and had decided to leave the country)  (Arya)

Comment: The Ambassador had invited the King on his own initiative 'a few days earlier' and had later obtained the Secretary's approval for the invitation.